Not able to access protected folder in windows using samba
Im using ubuntu server 24.04 lts and samba for file sharing to windows. The problem is im unable to open or connect to password protected folder but public/not protected folder can be accessed easily.
[test_folder]
  path = /test_folder
  read only = no
  valid user = usershiv

I've added the user using useradd usershiv -s /sbin/nologin and smbpasswd
and my folder permission are drwxrwxrwx 2 root root
Whereas the public folder can be accessed without any problem
[share folder] 
  path = /share_folder
  read only = no
  force user = nobody
  guest ok = yes

and this the permission for share folder drwxrwxrwx 3 nobody nogroup
I absolutely have no clue why its not working!? Please help me before i lose my sanity!!!!
